# git interactively review changes of a branch

Tags: git

In our research group, we often use git to collaboratively write papers (latex). Typically the lead author has "maintainer" role and control over master via github / gitlab, others contribute in feature branches by fixing typos, formulations, sections etc. (and typically don't or can't push to protected master).

Let's say the history looks like this:

```
A -- B -- C -- D <-- master
      \
       E -- F -- G <-- patch-1
```

Now as lead author / maintainer, i'd like to review the changes in the patch-1 branch. Typically it's part of a merge-request. If i agree with all of the changes in it, there is great tool support and i can simply merge. Sometimes however, i want to reject a line change. In those cases the tool support typically stops. I might be able to click "edit", but am now in patch-1's state and have to manually dig out B's versions for those changes that i don't want to accept.

Is there something like an interactive commit (`git commit --interactive`) that i can use to support me?

In the end i'm trying to generate a situation like this:

```
A -- B -- C -- D -------J <-- master
      \                /
       E -- F -- G -- H
```

Where `H` is my "review commit" that reverts unfitting changes from `E-G` and `J` is my then very simple merge.

Comment: Don't let everyone directly `push` to `master`. Set up something like GitHub, Bitbucket, etc that allows Pull Requests. Then you can review the pull requests before you deliver

Comment: exactly what we do... gitlab, github etc. however don't let you easily accept / reject individual changes (as in parts/lines of a pull request)... i'm searching support for that, preferrably hosting independent, directly in git

Comment: @CoryKramer updated the question accordingly

Comment: This has nothing to do with latex: you should delete that tag.

Comment: @Nick thought it helps to set the context, but ok, done...

Comment: would be great if downvoters left some feedback... i'm not really sure why this is a "negative" question...

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, i use the following simplistic (but probably sub-optimal) workflow:

```
git checkout -b tmp patch-1
git reset B
# now use my editor of choice that has git gutter (e.g., sublime text)
# review changes, revert those that i don't like, adapt others
# when done:
git reset patch-1
git commit -a
git checkout master
git merge tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

```
git checkout patch-1
# e.g. one change you don't like is in commit G
git revert G
git reset HEAD~
# At this point you have changes _reverting_ G in the index.
# Now you work on the index to get rid of the changes reverting those in G that you DO want to keep.
git commit
git checkout master
git merge patch-1
```

This workflow is moderately simpler than what you have, with two bonus points:

1. patch-1 remains push-compatible with the remote.
2. Your colleague's original changes are all preserved, and your modifications are explicitly kept in a separate commit.